# MySQL: table is marked as crashed

Tags: mysql

After a disk full issue one of the MySQL DBs on the server is coming up with the following error when I try to back it up:

```
[root@mybox ~]# mysqldump -p --result-file=/tmp/dbbackup.sql --database myDBname
Enter password:
mysqldump: Got error: 145: Table './myDBname/myTable1' is marked as crashed and should be repaired when using LOCK TABLES
```

A bit of investigation shows two tables have this issue.

What needs to be done to fix up the damaged tables?

Comment: myisam table storage?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To check the tables:

```
CHECK TABLE mytable1
```

To repair the table:

```
REPAIR TABLE mytable1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is specifically what always fixes the table for me:

```
myisamchk -o /var/lib/mysql/YourDB/yourcrashedtable.MYI
```

Source: http://realtechtalk.com/MySQL_table_is_marked_as_crashed_solultion-1924-articles

Answer (score 0):

Do this.

cd /var/lib/mysql/dbname
myisamchk --silent --force *.MYI